# Is 'sie' redundant here?

Tags: grammaticality

> Noch weniger als das Bootfahren an sich mochte er das Bootfahren auf einem der beiden neuen Schnellboote, die die Wasserschutzpolizei vor zwei Jahren nach langen verbissenen Kämpfen mit der Bürokratie erhalten hatte und deren ganzer Stolz **sie** waren.<sup>from: Jean-Luc Bannalec: Bretonische Brandung</sup>

Shouldn't it have read instead:

> ...und deren ganzer Stolz waren.

?

Comment: The example sentence is not constructed convincingly. In my opinion the *sie* is necessary, since *Schnellboote* is in a subordinate clause in the other part of the sentence and can't be taken for self-explaining or granted.

Comment: I agree the sentence is poorly constructed

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you interpret the structure of the sentence:

> die Schnellboote, die die Wasserschutzpolizei erhalten hatte.
>
> [die Schnellboote], deren ganzer Stolz **sie** waren

or:

> die Schnellboote, die die Wasserschutzpolizei erhalten hatte
>
> [die Schnellboote], die deren ganzer Stolz waren

Both possibilities work.

**EDIT**: I'll try to clarify what I mean:

Is the structure of the sentence

> ... die A (, die B) und C

or

> ... die A,(die B und C)

Comment: I can't recognize, what you are aiming at. There is only one party involved, which is able to feel *Stolz*, i.e. namely *Wasseschutzpolizei* and there is only one possible object, *Schnellboote*.

Comment: @guidot The problem is where does *und* split the sentence? In the subordinate clause, or before it?

Comment: In second interpretation there are two subordinate clauses connected by **und** which share the relative pronoun **die**. In the first interpretation there is only one subordinate clause consisting of two parts connected by **und**. Here the second part needs a subject and **sie** fills that role.

Comment: @RHa That's exactly what I was trying to say

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see a problem with the construction of the sentence and the simple answer to your question is: No, the word 'sie' is definitely not redundant in this sentence.

*sie* refers in this case to *Schnellboote* because these are the things the *Wasserschutzpolizei* is really proud of ("deren Stolz sie waren"). If you delete the word *sie* the sentence wouldn't make sense anymore.

You can also delete a part of the sentence, maybe the connection between *sie* and *Schnellboote* is clearer then:

> Noch weniger als das Bootfahren an sich mochte er das Bootfahren auf einem der beiden neuen Schnellboote, die die Wasserschutzpolizei … erhalten hatte und deren ganzer Stolz sie waren.

Answer (score 0):

Nein, 'sie' ist hier nicht redundant.
Ohne *sie* wird der Satz unverständlich.

Das ist eine hervorragende Frage! Denn obwohl die Antwort für ein deutsches Ohr eindeutig ausfällt, ist die grammatische Erklärung keinesfalls offensichtlich. Ich musste einige Zeit grübeln.

Die grammatische Erklärung ist:
Das erste *die* (das unmittelbar nach *Schnellboote* und dem Komma) steht **nicht** im Nominativ, sondern im Akkusativ, und ist daher **nicht** das Subjekt sondern das (Akkusativ-)Objekt des ersten Relativsatzes:

> Die Wasserschutzpolizei hatte **die** [Schnellboote] erhalten.

Würde man nun im zweiten Relativsatz das *sie* weg lassen, würde man das bisherige Subjekt als übernommen ansehen, und es käme folgender (falscher) Satz heraus:

> [Die Wasserschutzpolizei] waren ganzer Stolz.

Dieser Satz ist offensichtlich weder verständlich noch korrekt - Subjekt im Singular, Prädikat im Plural, Subjekt und Prädikat passen weder grammatisch noch inhaltlich zusammen.

Durch das Einfügen von *sie* wird dagegen alles passend sortiert:

> Sie [Schnellboote] waren deren [=der Wasserschutzpolizei] ganzer Stolz.

Comment: Ohne das *sie* wird der Satz nicht unverständlich, man muss sich dann aber ein zweites *die* denken: ...und *die* deren ganzer Stolz waren. Dieses *die* wegzulassen ist in der Tat etwas fragwürdig, da es zuerst im Akkusativ und danach im Nominativ steht.

Comment: @RHa Ich bin ganz und gar nicht einverstanden. "Ich esse Bananen und sind gelb." ist im Deutschen KEIN Satz. Zwar KÖNNTE man sich diesen als "Ich esse Bananen und (sie) sind gelb" denken, aber so funktioniert Deutsch nicht. Der Satz klingt falsch und ist falsch.

Comment: Der Vergleich ist nicht korrekt. Ein analoger Satz wäre "Ich esse Bananen, die ich mag und gelb sind." Holprig, aber nicht so eindeutig falsch wie das erste Beispiel.

Comment: @RHa Dein Satz ist näher am Satz des Fragestellers, weil in ihm das zu diskutierende Phänomen ebenfalls im Relativsatz ist. Dies ändert jedoch nichts am Phänomen selbst oder an seiner Bewertung. "Ich esse Bananen, die ich mag und gelb sind." ist nicht nur holprig, sondern schlichtweg falsch; man kann seine Bedeutung höchstens raten. Korrekt ist: "Ich esse Bananen, die ich mag und **die** gelb sind." Ratbarkeit ist kein Kriterium. Die Bedeutung von "Ich essen Bananen mag gelb" könnte man auch raten. Dadurch wird diese Ansammlung von Wörtern aber noch lange nicht zu einem deutschen Satz.

Answer (score -3):

With or without the "sie", the sentence is wrong; with the "sie", it doesn't say what the author probably intended, and without it it is grammatically wrong. The key point here is that the boats were the pride of the police and not versa, so you simply cannot conjoin these two clauses like that.

Comment: There is no problem understanding what the author means